How to cache room data in View Model?
In my Android app, I fetch data from the room database and display it on the UI.
I am caching mapped data. Is this the correct way to cache data in the View Model?
I am new to Android, please correct me if I am wrong.
I am switching dispatcher using withContext, do we need to switch?
@HiltViewModel
class TrainVM @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: Repository,  // Inject the repository
private val apiRepo: KtorRepo

) : ViewModel() {

   
    private var localSchCache = mutableMapOf<String, TrainSchStat>()
    private var trainSchCache = mutableMapOf<String, TrainWithNew>()

    private val _trainStatus =
        MutableStateFlow<ViewState<TrainWithNew>>(value = ViewState.Loading)
    val trainStatus = _trainStatus.asStateFlow()

    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val isLoading = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

    fun fetchTrain(train: String, isLive: Boolean, date: LocalDate?) {
        _isLoading.update { true }
        _trainStatus.update { ViewState.Loading }
        if (isLive) {
            loadTrainStatus(train, date = date) //loads live status using API data
        } else {
            loadSchedule(train = train) // loads data from room
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////

    private fun loadSchedule(
        train: String,
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val localSch = localSchCache[train] ?: repo.getSch(train)
                        .also { localSchCache[train] = it }

                    val trainSch = trainSchCache[train]
                        ?: mappedTrainToStation(localSch).also {
                            trainSchCache[train] = it
                        }

                    _trainStatus.update { ViewState.Success(data = trainSch) }
                }
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                _trainStatus.update {
                    ViewState.Error(
                        message = exception.message ?: "An unknown error occurred"
                    )
                }
            } finally {
                _isLoading.update { false }
            }
        }
    }
private fun loadTrainStatus(
    train: String,
    date: LocalDate? = null,
) {

   viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val localData = localSchCache[train] ?: repo.getSch(train)
                .also { localSchCache[train] = it }

            apiRepo.fetchTrainStatus(train).onSuccess { apiData ->
                val mappedData = mappedTrainToStation(localData, apiData)
        _trainStatus.update { ViewState.Success(data = mappedData) }
            }.onFailure { exception ->
                _trainStatus.update {
                    ViewState.Error(
                        message = exception.message ?: "An unknown error"
                    )
                }
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            _trainStatus.update {
                ViewState.Error(
                    message = exception.message ?: "An unknown error occurred"
                )
            }
        } finally {
            _isLoading.update { false }
        }
    }
}

The code works fine as desired, I want to ensure I am doing the correct thing.

Hello, can you please approve/reject my edit? thank you.
